# VS 2019 и GIT, при слиянии меняется перевод строк

Tags: git, git-merge, visual-studio-2019, gitkraken

При Merge возникает такая проблема как на скриншоте, меняется перевод строк у файла с **Unix LF** на **Windows CRLF**. Как эту проблему решить?

В документации по VS нашел ["Кодировки и окончания строк"](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/ide/encodings-and-line-breaks?view=vs-2019), но у меня нету этих настроек, в том числе меню Сервиса о котором говорится в примечании

Использую версию VS 2019 Community
Для слияния использовал GitKraken

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: *"подозрение что меняется перевод строк у файла с CRLF на LF"* - так оно меняется или нет? в исходных файлах все было в порядке? *"у меня нету этих настроек"* - не может быть.

Comment: @user7860670 в исходных файлах все было в порядке, изменений там не было. Если подскажите как можно узнать, поменялся перевод или нет, то смогу ответить точно

Comment: В VS в панели с горизонтальным скролбаром для документов справа отображается режим табуляции и окончания строк в документе...

Comment: @user7860670 добавил скриншот, ничего похожего на режиме табуляции или окончание строк не вижу

Comment: Может быть у вас оно все выключено? Загляните в настройки в Text editor -> General -> Display -> Show editing context in the editor.

Comment: @user7860670 открыл настройки текстового редактора, в разделе "общие" нету подраздела Display, добавил скриншот

Comment: Хм, у меня это окно выглядит [так](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjkij.png). Ну откройте в Notepad++ - там можно включить отображение непечатыемых символов

Comment: @user7860670 открыл обычным блокнотом, до merge "UTF-8", после "UTF-8 со спецификацией"

Comment: UTF-8 со спецификацией - это кодировка, а не окончание строк, хотя она по идее тоже не должна меняться

Comment: @user7860670 Меняется с Unix LF на Windows CRLF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После обновления Visual Studio появилась возможность изменить перевод строк посредством студии, которая решает эту проблему с переносом для gitkraken